# Loading next level Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Heres my first attempt at loading the next level upon reaching "Goal"

```
public int CurrentLevel = 0;
public static int maxlevel = 3;

public void CompleteLevel()
{
    if (CurrentLevel < maxlevel)
    {
        CurrentLevel += 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(CurrentLevel);
    }
    else
        print("you win");
}
```

This is in another class...

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "DeathObject")
        Die();
    if (other.transform.tag == "Goal")
    Manager.CompleteLevel();
}
```

It ended up loading the first level, went to the second, then it would repeat the second map when i reached goal. Another thing it would do is skip to the last level from the first or second level.. not sure whats going on there. Heres the second thing i tried:

```
public void LevelPassTest()
{
    if (Application.loadedLevel > 4)
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel + 1);
        else
    print("win");
}
```

This is in another class....

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "DeathObject")
        Die();
    if (other.transform.tag == "Goal")
    Manager.LevelPassTest();
}
```

I'm not sure why, but sometimes it doesn't load the next level, it worked for a while then stopped, after I reset unity it works again, so I'm not sure if it's my code or unity... I get a warning message that says "Warning  CS0618  'Application.loadedLevel' is obsolete: 'Use SceneManager to determine what scenes have been loaded'" and "Warning   CS0618  'Application.LoadLevel(int)' is obsolete: 'Use SceneManager.LoadScene'" I'm new to coding and completely lost on this. spent 4 hours trying to fix it. What are these warnings? can they be effecting the loading? I was also wanting to be able to save the value of the level so i can use it in game saves, and attach high scores to it. I tried using this in my first attempt, but it didn't work how i was hoping. (CurrentLevel)

Comment: The warning you get is precisely telling you what to do.

Comment: @ Measuring well i don't know how to use scenemanager without making it look like my first attempt, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are your scenes correctly added to the Build Settings?
   Go to File > Build Settings... and check in "Scenes In Build" whether all your scenes from scene #0 to scene #3 are added the way you need them.
2. The first example you gave should work, **however** you have to make sure, that your first script (containing `CurrentLevel`) is not destroyed on loading the next scene. Do this by calling `GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` in its `void Start()`. Alternatively you can make `CurrentLevel` a static member.
   This is necessary so the value of `CurrentLevel` is not lost when loading the next scene. This would explain why you kept loading the same level over and over.
3. In your second example, in LevelPassTest() you check if `Application.loadedLevel > 4`, this of course has to be `Application.loadedLevel < 4`. If you fix this, the second example should work just fine, too.

And yes, you are partially working on obsolete API, but that does not explain why it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

`Application.LoadLevel` and the rest are obsolete as of Unity 5. You have to use `SceneManager` instead.

So `Application.LoadLevel()` is now `SceneManager.LoadScene()`.

You must also include `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`

See here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

All it takes is a quick Google.

Answer (score 0):

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

and then use SceneManager.LoadScene() the same way we used to use Application.LoadLevel(), in unity 5.x.x Application.LoadLevel is obsolete - meaning it will be removed in the future and should not be used, and it is not guaranteed that it will work properly.

I recommend you read Unity's documentation on Scene and SceneManager classes so you can get familiar with the changes unity 5 introduced.